# this message pops up in a terminal window whenever i try to open steam, how do i fix it?

Tags: apt, steam

this message pops up in a terminal window whenever i try to open steam, then all my games are seemingly uninstalled but they are still in my library, im really inexperienced with linux so i have no idea how to resolve this.

````
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 1068, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 899, in main
    package = create_package(section)
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 392, in create_package
    name = remap_package(name)
  File "/usr/bin/steamdeps", line 325, in remap_package
    cache = apt.Cache()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 170, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 232, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
apt_pkg.Error: E:Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://repo.steampowered.com/steam/ stable: /usr/share/keyrings/steam.gpg != , E:The list of sources could not be read.```
````

Comment: `E:Conflicting values set for option Signed-By...` suggests that you tried to install that repo multiple times, that you followed at least two different sets of instructions, and that you didn't clean up between attempts.